# Use jQuery tab form with FormData

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using a jQuery multi-tabbed widget, but I want it all the be one form. So with inputs in all sections.

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Section 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Section 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <form>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Value 1</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Value 1</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
      <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I want all tabs to have inputs and be associated with one form. I'm just unsure how to structure it and where to place the `<form></form>` tags so that it knows the inputs in all the tabs belong to the one form.

Comment: Every form control element inside the form tags are members of that form, nevertheless they are wrapped in some other elements.

Comment: @Teemu I understand, so what about the edited example?

Comment: Both the inputs are "belonging" to the form. Notice, that only form control elements (input, select, textarea) are taken in a FormData object, elements like div and p are ignored. Also, it's recommended that the form control elements have the name attribute being set.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you, I just put them inputs in as examples. I will of course give them name attributes. I just wanted to make sure the structure was correct first. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "form" tag must wrap your entire code above

Comment: it should be like that yes